# Why is tvOS SearchController Not Working?

Tags: xcode, tvos, uisearchcontroller

This worked until a recent update of tvOS.  Any ideas what happened?  The search bar is still present in the app, it just skips straight over it to the tableview.

When the app first was released, everything worked fine, but at some point, it simply quit working.  I don't get any errors in console, and everything says it is allocated and initialized.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _resultsTableController = [[APLResultsTableController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others


    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
        }
    }
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"AIMPDF"];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self.files objectAtIndex:thepath.row];

    self.title = @"Devo Songs";
    self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);

    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.files count]];
    for (NSString *path in self.files) {
        [names addObject:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }

    self.files = names;
    self.files = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphonebackground.png"]];
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // update the filtered array based on the search text
    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchResults2 = [self.files mutableCopy];

    // strip out all the leading and trailing spaces
    NSString *strippedString = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    // break up the search terms (separated by spaces)
    NSArray *searchItems = nil;
    if (strippedString.length > 0) {
        searchItems = [strippedString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    }

    // build all the "AND" expressions for each value in the searchString
    //
    NSMutableArray *andMatchPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *searchString in searchItems) {
        // each searchString creates an OR predicate for: name, yearIntroduced, introPrice
        //
        // example if searchItems contains "iphone 599 2007":
        //      name CONTAINS[c] "iphone"
        //      name CONTAINS[c] "599", yearIntroduced ==[c] 599, introPrice ==[c] 599
        //      name CONTAINS[c] "2007", yearIntroduced ==[c] 2007, introPrice ==[c] 2007
        //
        NSPredicate *sPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchString];
        [searchResults2 filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];

        // at this OR predicate to our master AND predicate
       // NSCompoundPredicate *orMatchPredicates = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:searchItemsPredicate];
        //[andMatchPredicates addObject:orMatchPredicates];
    }

    // match up the fields of the Product object
  //  NSCompoundPredicate *finalCompoundPredicate =
    //[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:andMatchPredicates];
    //searchResults2 = [[searchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:finalCompoundPredicate] mutableCopy];

    // hand over the filtered results to our search results table
    APLResultsTableController *tableController = (APLResultsTableController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
    tableController.filteredProducts = searchResults2;
    [tableController.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];
        array = nil;
    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSString *currentString in [self files])
        {
            if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentString];
            }
        }
    }
}- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created.
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] text]];

    [self setSearchResults:nil];
}
/*
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }
 */
/*
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
 */
/*
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }
 */
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
        return YES;
    }

#else

    // iPhone simulator
    return YES;

#endif
}

/*- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self handleSearchForTerm:searchString];

    return YES;
}
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:nil];

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}*/
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger rows;

        rows = [[self files] count];
    return rows;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *filename = [[[self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;


        contentForThisRow = filename;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


           [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:90];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {

        return 80;
    }
    else {
        return 120;
    }

}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    //this gives you the indexpath of the focused cell
    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
    NSLog(@"Do Something");
}

/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source.
 NSString *selectedHtml = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


 [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedHtml] error:NULL];

 [self.files removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedCountry = (tableView == self.tableView) ?
    self.files[indexPath.row] : self.resultsTableController.filteredProducts[indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSong" sender:self];




}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSong"])
    {

        NSLog(@"Selecting %@", self.selectedCountry);
        FirstViewController* userViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        userViewController.selectedCountry = self.selectedCountry;

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the search controller stop working in the released version of the app? Or does it only fail when you try to build from Xcode?

Comment: @JulianMinde it stopped working in the released version of the app.  Worked fine, updated the Apple TV, it stopped working.  It still shows the search bar, but then it just gets skipped over, no way to select it.

Comment: do you have navigation controller?

Comment: @user717452 can i look into your project?

Comment: What is the version of the updated tvOS?

Comment: @swift2geek I could email it to you? It's on the latest tvOS, whatever that is. 12.X something

Comment: @user717452 swift2geek@gmail.com

Comment: @swift2geek Just emailed it out to you

Comment: updated version 12.1

Comment: how that searchbar should functioniert? should it be scrollable or stick on top of tableView? its a header of tableview as i see. and the current problem is that its not interactable, right? you cant input there nothing

Comment: @swift2geek. It used to be selectable and I could hover on it and click trackpad to pull up search text box and type in song to search

Comment: @swift2geek Find anything?